# Replacing certain NA values with a specific value

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to edit NAs in my data for visualization purposes. I would like to replace some of the NAs with the value "31". However, I only want the NAs replaced in the column "Cq" only where "Dilution" = 1 or 1:1. Here is an example of my data frame:

| Sample | Dilution | Cq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | NA |
| 1 | 1:1 | NA |
| 1 | 1:5 | 27 |
| 2 | 1 | 13 |
| 2 | 1:1 | 14 |
| 2 | 1:5 | 15 |

I've been trying `mutate_if` and `na_replace` but I lack knowledge about the syntax to do this appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `ifelse` (or `case_when`) with your conditions:

```
your_data %>%
  mutate(Cq = ifelse(is.na(Cq) & Dilution %in% c("1", "1:1"), 31, Cq))
#   Sample Dilution Cq
# 1      1        1 31
# 2      1      1:1 31
# 3      1      1:5 27
# 4      2        1 13
# 5      2      1:1 14
# 6      2      1:5 15
```

---

Using this data:

```
your_data = read.table(text = 'Sample   Dilution    Cq
1   1   NA
1   1:1     NA
1   1:5     27
2   1   13
2   1:1     14
2   1:5     15', header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `data.table` package, I've written some code below illustrating how you would be able to replace the `NA` values of `Cq` only when `Dilution` is 1 or 1:1.

```
library(data.table)

data <- data.table(
  Sample = c("1","1","1","2","2","2"),
  Dilution = c("1","1:1","1:5","1","1:1","1:5"),
  Cq = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 27, 13, 14, 15))

data
Sample Dilution Cq
1:      1        1 NA
2:      1      1:1 NA
3:      1      1:5 27
4:      2        1 13
5:      2      1:1 14
6:      2      1:5 15

data[Dilution %in% c("1","1:1") & is.na(Cq)] <- 31

data
   Sample Dilution Cq
1:     31       31 31
2:     31       31 31
3:      1      1:5 27
4:      2        1 13
5:      2      1:1 14
6:      2      1:5 15
```

Answer (score 0):

`replace` option like this:

```r
df <- read.table(text = "Sample Dilution    Cq
1   1   NA
1   1:1 NA
1   1:5 27
2   1   13
2   1:1 14
2   1:5 15
", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Cq = replace(Cq, is.na(Cq) & Dilution == "1" | Dilution == "1:1", 31))
#>   Sample Dilution Cq
#> 1      1        1 31
#> 2      1      1:1 31
#> 3      1      1:5 27
#> 4      2        1 13
#> 5      2      1:1 31
#> 6      2      1:5 15
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>